# Treatment of P and NP as sets in ZFC/NBG?

Tags: set-theory, computer-science, computational-complexity

I have recently being working a lot with axiomatic set theory, and one of the first things I picked up on is that all members of a set are themselves sets. For example, $2 \in \mathbb{N}$ and $2 = \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}$.

However, how is this supposed to apply to P and NP in computational complexity? Both are described as sets, yet it seems that the problems they contain are not sets. I've sometimes also heard P and NP referred to "complexity *classes*" rather than sets, but I'm not sure if that's the same thing as a class in the NBG sense. (and even if it were, it wouldn't solve the issue because members of NBG classes are also sets.)

Is there some hand-waving (on the part of either set theorists or computer scientists) at work here? Or am I just failing to understand a key detail?

Comment: No, both P and NP are(or at least can be encoded) sets.

Comment: @Shinrin-Yoku Well, yeah I get that much. What I am asking is "*How* are they expressed as sets, since their members do *not* seem to be sets?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If we restrict to a fixed (finite) alphabet at the outset** - say, we look at all languages over *(= sets of strings formed from)* the alphabet $\{0,1\}$ - then complexity classes are sets without further complications. In particular, if we use the alphabet $\{0,1\}$, then each complexity class is a subset of the set $\{0,1\}^{<\omega}$ of finite binary strings (and in particular an element of a complexity class is simply a subset of $\{0,1\}^{<\omega}$). Any finite alphabet - well, with more than one element :P - is sufficient for our purposes, so $\{0,1\}$ is a standard choice here.

However, sometimes complexity classes are defined so as to make sense over *any* finite alphabet whatsoever. In this case, complexity classes really are proper classes, but only for the rather silly reason that the class of finite alphabets is already a proper class. So *technically* if the text you're reading adopts a super-unnecessary level of generality at the outset, this may feel like an issue.

But even in that case, classes aren't appearing in a substantive way: if we fix a countably infinite alphabet $\Sigma$, then every finite language is equivalent in every imaginably relevant sense to *(more precisely, is in bijection with)* a finite subalphabet of $\Sigma$, and so we can "collapse back down" to the set-context.

Comment: So how are the *members* of a complexity class expressed in set form?

Comment: They are literally just binary strings @Nicolino

Comment: So is reducing the elements to binary strings a trivial action or is there a formal proof of it somewhere?

Comment: @Shinrin-Yoku Not quite - a member of a complexity class is a *set of* finite binary strings.

Comment: @Nicolino I've usually seen it as an exercise; it's quite easy (I'm not sure I'd call it "trivial," but that's more because *stating it precisely* is a bit subtle - once stated correctly, it's very easy to prove). But if you don't want to take it for granted, just use the approach in my last paragraph - that still resolves the set/class concern completely.

Comment: Yes that is what I meant, I should said collection.